# Registros por día de la semanal php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito crear un código php que me traiga los registros por día de la semana. Osea cuantos usuarios se registraron el Lunes, el Martes, El miércoles... y así hasta el domingo.. que se calcule por el numero de semana actual.

Se puede hacer algo así? lo he echo por rango de fechas o por una fecha determinada.
Pero quisiera hacerlo por día de la semana. osea semanalmente.

EJEMPLO:

Lunes: 85 
Martes: 32 
Miércoles: 65 
Jueves: 18 
Viernes: 3 (Día actual) 
Sábado: 0  
Domingo: 0

```html
<?php
include("conexion.php");

$semana_actual = date('W');
$dif = $semana_actual - $semana_actual;

$actual = date('W');
$calculo1 = date('W')+1;
$calculo2 = $actual - $calculo1;

$fecha_lunes = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Monday $calculo2 week"));
$fecha_martes = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Tuesday $calculo2 week"));
$fecha_miercoles = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Wednesday $dif week"));
$fecha_jueves = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Thursday $dif week"));
$fecha_viernes = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Friday $dif week"));
$fecha_sabado = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Saturday $dif week"));
$fecha_domingo = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Sunday $dif week"));

$sql_lunes=mysqli_query($conexion,"select count(*) cuenta1 from persona where fecha_inscripcion like '%".$fecha_lunes."%'")or die("error consulta1");
IF($row_lunes=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_lunes)){
$lunes=$row_lunes["cuenta1"];
}

$sql_martes=mysqli_query($conexion,"select count(*) cuenta2 from persona where fecha_inscripcion like '%".$fecha_martes."%'")or die("error consulta2");
IF($row_martes=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_martes)){
$martes=$row_martes["cuenta2"];
}

$sql_miercoles=mysqli_query($conexion,"select count(*) cuenta3 from persona where fecha_inscripcion like '%".$fecha_miercoles."%'")or die("error consulta3");
IF($row_miercoles=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_miercoles)){
$miercoles=$row_miercoles["cuenta3"];
}

$sql_jueves=mysqli_query($conexion,"select count(*) cuenta4 from persona where fecha_inscripcion like '%".$fecha_jueves."%'")or die("error consulta4");
IF($row_jueves=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_jueves)){
$jueves=$row_jueves["cuenta4"];
}

$sql_viernes=mysqli_query($conexion,"select count(*) cuenta5 from persona where fecha_inscripcion like '%".$fecha_viernes."%'")or die("error consulta5");
IF($row_viernes=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_viernes)){
$viernes=$row_viernes["cuenta5"];
}

$sql_sabado=mysqli_query($conexion,"select count(*) cuenta6 from persona where fecha_inscripcion like '%".$fecha_sabado."%'")or die("error consulta6");
IF($row_sabado=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_sabado)){
$sabado=$row_sabado["cuenta6"];
}

$sql_domingo=mysqli_query($conexion,"select count(*) cuenta7 from persona where fecha_inscripcion like '%".$fecha_domingo."%'")or die("error consulta7");
IF($row_domingo=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_domingo)){
$domingo=$row_domingo["cuenta7"];
}

echo $lunes; echo "<br>";
echo $martes; echo "<br>";
echo $miercoles; echo "<br>";
echo $jueves; echo "<br>";
echo $viernes; echo "<br>";
echo $sabado; echo "<br>";
echo $domingo; echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Si se puede hacer, pero, ¿tu has intentado algo?, si has intentado algo coloca tu código por favor. Saludos.

Comment: ya adjunte lo q llevo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues lo primero, lo que deseas hacer se puede hacer desde la DB, utilizando las funciones de MySQL `WEEK` para obtener el número de semana del año y `DAYNAME` para obtener el nombre del dia de la semana según la fecha (en mi ejemplo añadí `SET @@lc_time_names = 'es_SV';` para cambiar el lenguaje, en mi caso a español de El Salvador), luego utilizar PHP para mostrar el resultado, algo así:

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
    
$sql = "SET @@lc_time_names = 'es_SV';
    
sELECT 
FECHA,
CASE
    WHEN DAYNAME(FECHA) = 'lunes' THEN 1
    WHEN DAYNAME(FECHA) = 'martes' THEN 2
    WHEN DAYNAME(FECHA) = 'miércoles' THEN 3
    WHEN DAYNAME(FECHA) = 'jueves' THEN 4
    WHEN DAYNAME(FECHA) = 'viernes' THEN 5
    WHEN DAYNAME(FECHA) = 'sábado' THEN 6
    WHEN DAYNAME(FECHA) = 'domingo' THEN 7
END ORDEN,
DAYNAME(FECHA) DIA,
COUNT(FECHA) REGISTROS FROM PERSONA
WHERE WEEK(FECHA)= WEEK(CURDATE())
GROUP BY FECHA,DAYNAME(FECHA)
ORDER BY ORDEN;";
    
if (mysqli_multi_query($conexion, $sql)) {
    do {
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conexion)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo 'Dia: '.$row[1];
        echo ' Registros: '.$row[2].'<br><br>';
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    if (mysqli_more_results($conexion)) {
        printf("\n");
    }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($conexion));
}
    
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo del dataset que utilice para que lo puedas adecuar a tu implementacion.

<kbd>[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=010bcc5f9af312c7584ced45dc26e2c7)</kbd>

Espero que sea lo que buscas. Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto. me funciono. como hago para que el dia de la semana comience por el Lunes... osea que sea de lunes a domingo.. lo muestra es de domingo a sábado.

Comment: Puedes añadir un `case` con el nombre del dia y añadir el orden (aunque después no lo imprimas en PHP), edite la pregunta para que puedas ver a qué me refiero, también ten en cuenta que quizá sea importante mostrar la fecha a la que corresponde el dia (creo). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si todavía estés buscando solución a tu problema pero tomando de referencia la respuesta que te dieron y que tenía un desafío muy parecido al tuyo, pude llegar a una posible solución que comparto y espero y te pueda ser de utilidad.

```
    SET @@lc_time_names = 'es_MX';

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`fecha`,'%d/%m/%Y') as FechaRegistro, 
CASE 
WHEN DAYNAME(fecha) = 'Lunes' THEN 1 
WHEN DAYNAME(fecha) = 'Martes' THEN 2 
WHEN DAYNAME(fecha) = 'Miércoles' THEN 3
WHEN DAYNAME(fecha) = 'Jueves' THEN 4 
WHEN DAYNAME(fecha) = 'Viernes' THEN 5 
WHEN DAYNAME(fecha) = 'Sábado' THEN 6 
WHEN DAYNAME(fecha) = 'Domingo' THEN 7 
END ORDEN,
MONTHNAME(fecha) MES, 
DAYNAME(fecha) DIA, 
count(fecha) REGISTROS FROM miTabla 
WHERE MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(NOW()) 
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha), DAYNAME(fecha) 
ORDER BY ORDEN;
```

Answer (score -1):

Si usas base de datos, suena fácil ya que solo necesitarías incluir el día en la tabla y después mediante un query retornas esos datos.

Comment: Un ejemplo ayudaría a mejorar tu aporte que al momento luce más como un comentario

Comment: si claro utilizo BD y tengo un capo de fecha. q es la fecha de registro de la persona.  a raíz de esa fecha es que quiero sacar cuantas personas se registraron en cada dia de la semana. agregue parte del código que llevo. pero nada aun.